# Error Query multiple documents in a loop Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have the following structure in firestore.

> • conversations - {convid}
>
> - messages - {messageId}
> - field array offline [user ids]
>
> • users - {userid} - devices - {deviceids}

So the usecase is whenever a new message is sent by a user, a triggered cloud function checks the offline array containing the userids of all offline users in the group.

Now while iterating and later sending a push to offline users, the iteration only shows multiple queries to the user on the last index of the array in the for loop.

The logs in cloud function are

> The array of offline users is => [ '919XXXXX5565', '919XXXXX9334',
>   '9190XXXXX608','919XXXXX1818', '919XXXXX9974', '9197XXXXX661',
>   '9181XXXXX854' ]
>
> 2:56:22.043 AM Current user id: 919XXXXX5565
>
> 2:56:22.044 AM Current user id: 919XXXXX334
>
> 2:56:22.044 AM Current user id: 9190XXXXX608
>
> 2:56:22.044 AM Current user id: 919XXXXX1818
>
> 2:56:22.044 AM Current user id: 919XXXXX9974
>
> 2:56:22.044 AM Current user id: 9197XXXXX661
>
> 2:56:22.044 AM Current user id: 9181XXXXX854
>
> 2:56:22.046 AM Successfully prepared token list false
>
> 2:56:22.151 AM Function execution took 5097 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
>
> 2:56:22.188 AM No matching documents. for => 9181XXXXX854
>
> 2:56:22.190 AM No matching documents. for => 9181XXXXX854
>
> 2:56:22.229 AM No matching documents. for => 9181XXXXX854
>
> 2:56:22.231 AM No matching documents. for => 9181XXXXX854
>
> 2:56:22.233 AM No matching documents. for => 9181XXXXX854
>
> 2:56:22.237 AM No matching documents. for => 9181XXXXX854

**My Code**

```
var outputList = [];
var promises = [];   
return admin.firestore().collection('conversations').doc(conversationDocId).get();
    .then(document =>{
              let offline = []
              if(!document.exists){
                  return false;
              } else{
                  try{
                    offline = document.data().offline;
                    console.log("The array of offline users is =>", offline);
                  }catch(offlineError){
                    console.error("offline array does not exist" + offlineError);
                  }

                  for(uid of offline) {
                    console.log("Current user id: " + uid);
                    let promise = admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(uid).collection('devices').get()
                        .then(snapshot => {
                            if (snapshot.empty) {
                                console.log('No matching documents. for =>', uid);
                            }
                            snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                                try {
                                    token = doc.data().rt
                                    outputList.push(token);
                                } catch (tokenfetcherror) {
                                    console.error("unable to fetch token for =>", uid);
                                }
                            });
                            return;
                        }).catch(errtoken => {
                            console.error('Error getting documents', errtoken);
                        });
                    promises.push(promise);
                }

                Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
                    return outputList;
                }).catch(err => {
                    return err;
                })
              }
              return false;
          })
```

I picked this from https://stackoverflow.com/a/57739544/1468797

Comment: Your function needs to return a promise that resolves only after all other promises have resovled from the async work you started.

Comment: I think it's doing that, the problem looks to be more with just the logging. I am using uid in the log, which is outside the asynchronous execution. and thus it's only picking the last value in the iteration

Comment: Moreover this is a almost the same code as in the answer link above. but the part3 video from you video tutorial really heled clean this up. Thanks Doug

Comment: You're ignoring the promise returned by `Promise.all()`.  Returning `false` is not the thing to do when you have nested promises.

Comment: yes fixed that already after looking at the video. btw is nesting promises inside a for loop a good practice? I think I saw a warning regarding this while building